# Ruby. The strange argv[0] element in the array being an argument of the spawn method

Tags: ruby, process

As is known, the Ruby's *Kernel#spawn* method executes the specified command and returns its pid. The method can accept either a whole command line as a single argument, a command name and any number of the command's arguments or an array where the first element is the command itself and the second is, according to the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Kernel#spawn-instance_method), the strange variable *argv[0]*. As it turned out, the variable has nothing to do with the Ruby's ARGV[0].

What is this variable? What does it contain?

Thanks.

Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.2;

Ruby 1.9.3-p0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a variable at all.

When executing a command (in the general case), the arguments go into `argv[1]` to `argv[*n*]`. The name of the command executed can be found in `argv[0]`. (For Ruby applications, they will be placed in `ARGV`, for C applications they can be accessed using the `argc` and `argv` arguments to `main`.)

By default, `argv[0]` will be the same as the command started. However, if you use following form:

```
exec(["alpha", "beta"])
```

The program `alpha` will be executed, but it's `argv[0]` will be `beta`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, **Lindy**. I think, I start to understand. In C there's the `argv[0]` "variable". By default it contains the name of the current program. Using Ruby's `spawn` I can change that value at the C's program start. In this connection another question has occured to me. How can I utilize this opportunity and why it might be needed at all?

Comment: Some programs do things differently depending on the name given. For example, on some system `grep`, behave differently if it was started with the name `egrep`. Also, the second name turns up when listing processes, so you could specify a more descriptive name than the name of the actual executable file.